# Unable to login after accidentally modifying authorised_keys in Vagrant VM

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, authorization, ssh-keys

I have accidentally modified the default `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file which comes in Vagrant VM and unable to login to that VM using `vagrant ssh`. How do I fix this, so that I can login using `vagrant up && vagrant ssh`. Are there any modifications that I need to do in Vagrantfile that adds the public key or my host machine to list of authorized_keys on Vagrant VM?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you didn't make any modification manually, you can just destroy the VM using `vagrant destroy` and then invoke `vagrant up && vagrant ssh`.